# How do I set content negotiation for .jsonld files and .html?

Tags: apache, json-ld, linked-data, content-negotiation, http-status-code-303

I'm developing a Linked Data application and I need to use 303 URIs for my dataset. Currently, I have a dataset of 22500 .jsonld files with URIs as follows:

```
http://example.com/project/resource/file.jsonld
```

And I want to redirect browsers looking for text/html content to:

```
http://example.com/project/page/file.html
```

Which are not semantic files, so they are more readable.

Does anyone know how can I do this with Apache 2.4.10? I've been considering the type-map files, but I was wondering if there are another more efficient solutions than creating 22500 .var files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [W3C: Best Practice Recipes for Publishing RDF Vocabularies](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/NOTE-swbp-vocab-pub-20080828/). Although it is about publishing vocabularies, it lists a number of recipes for configuring content negotiation on Apache that apply equally to datasets.

The other key documentation for doing this is [Apache Module mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).